# Laravel JSON to Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, jsondecoder

I have to convert json to arry from the laravel notifications table `data` field,

This is the the data shown on `dd($user->notifications);`

[image]

This is how the response shows in the postman
[image]

I need to show the payload within `[]` as below

```
 {
    "payload": [ {
        "title": "PHP Developer Accepted",
        "description": "<p>This is a professional IT Job&nbsp;</p>",
        "user_id": 54,
        "job_id": "01"
    }],
    "message": "",
    "result": true
}
```

Here's my controller index function

```
protected function index()
{
    $user = DeviceAuthenticator::getUserByAccessToken();

    foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {
        $notifications = $notification->data;
    }

    return response()->apiSuccess($notifications); 
}
```

But before I dump the $notifications before response it shows as an array

```
dd($notifications);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap in `[]` your variable  which will be like

```php
protected function index()
{
    $user = DeviceAuthenticator::getUserByAccessToken();

    foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {
        $notifications = $notification->data;
    }

    return response()->apiSuccess([$notifications]);  // wrap in array
}
```

---

#### You may need something like this

```php
protected function index()
{
    $user = DeviceAuthenticator::getUserByAccessToken();

    $notifications = [];
    foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {
        $notifications[] = $notification->data;
    }

    return response()->apiSuccess($notifications);
}
```

here `notifications` is an array

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this
->toArray();